# Question about Relationships and Accessors in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

The documentation doesn't seem to mention my problem (or I'm blind) so I wanted to ask here.
I have a Student model and a Condition (medical condition) model. And there's a 3rd model to serve as the pivot table to assign Conditions to Students (many-to-many relationship).
The StudentCondition model has 3 columns: student_id, condition_id and level.
I need the "level" column on the StudentCondition pivot model to store the intensity level of that medical condition on that specific student.
So far everything works correctly, the relationship works, and I can get each student conditions correctly, but there's one point I'm trying to upgrade and can't get my head around how.
Right now when I access a student condition it comes formatted like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Atraso na fala",
    "pivot" : {
        "student_id" : 34,
        "condition_id": 12,
        "level" : 2
    }
}
```

I wanted to define an accessor for the characteristics property on the Student model and format the characteristics to include the level information on the same level of the Condition name, instead of inside the pivot object.
But in Laravel 10, to define an accessor I need to define a protected function with the name of the property to formatted, but this function name is already occupied by the relationship definition. So, how am I supposed to name the Accessor function for the characteristics property if the characteristics() function already exists on my model? Is there a secondary naming method for Accessors? Or are Accessors for relationships just not possible?

Comment: *"And there's a 3rd model to serve as the pivot table"* - Typically, you don't define a Model for your Pivot table. You can, but it's generally not accessed, since you'd do `foreach($student->conditions as $condition)`, then `$condition->pivot` would contain the FK links and other pivot columns. But, for your actual question, you can name the method whatever you'd like, i.e. `protected function example(): Attribute { ... }`, and inside of that you can access any property of `$this` (i.e. the Model instance you're currently referencing), like `$this->pivot->level` would be `2`.

Comment: `you can name the method whatever you'd like` But then, how would Laravel know when to run this Accessor? The documentation says that I need to define an acessor method with the name of the property I'm mutating in camel case. If I change my Accessor method to anything else, how can I ensure it will run and format my conditions property when I try to access it?

Comment: *"how would Laravel know when to run this Accessor?"* - When you actually call it. If you name the accessor `example()`, when you run `$student->example`, it will run your accessor  I've personally never had any success naming an Accessor the same as the attribute it's trying to mutate, since it removes the ability to access the base value. If I have something like `$model->date`, which is a `string`, but I want a `DateTime` (or `Carbon` instance), I would define an accessor `public function getDateTimeAttribute()`, or `protected function dateTime(): Attribute`, then call `$model->date_time`

Comment: (The above is a bad example, since you would just use Casts or Model Dates to make it so accessing `$model->date` would return a `DateTime` or `Carbon` instance by default, but you get the idea)

Comment: It occurs to me that I never considered the possibility of just straight up calling the accessor method ('-')... that should do the trick, thanks!

Comment: Almost; calling the method would be `$model->example()`, which returns an `Attribute` instance, which has `get()`, `set()`, `withCaching` and `withObjectCaching` properties, and you can't do much else with it (`$model->example->get()` fails, for instance). Behind the scenes, Laravel converts this `example()` method to a property `example`, which, depending on usage (`$model->example` vs `$model->example = ...`), calls the `get()` or `set()` method magically. They're apparently a lot more complicated in more recent versions of Laravel 

Answer (score 0):

something like

```php
class Condition
{
  public function getLevelAttribute(): ?int
  {
    return $this->pivot?->level;
  }
}
```

now you can do

```php
$student->conditions->each(fn (Condition $condition) => $condition->level);
```